# Eclipse no more showing android "Added in API Level" on mouse over

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Before updating everything(ADT, build tools, API Level), eclipse used to show "Added in API Level" at the end of description when I mouse over on any class or a method. But now after updating to latest versions, it gone. I double checked, I have downloaded the source, documentation and all. But still nothing.

Currently I have

- SDK Tools 23.0.5
- SDK Platform-tools 21
- SD Build-tools 21.1.1
- API 21

Answer (score 0):

When you use a method that has higher API than your minSDK, eclipse will put a red line under it, and show you a warning there.

Comment: It does and sometimes it doesn't. And few times I found that out after testing and a crash.

Comment: do you by any chance have 
lintOptions {abortOnError false}
in your build.gradle??????
http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck